# Initialize static Array of functions with NULL values

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, static

i have the following class:

```
class A
{
public:
    static void (*callbacks[6])();
};
```

And i need to initialize all values of callbacks, to NULL.

How is that done?

I have tried the following:

```
void (* )[6]() A::callbacks[6] = {
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
};
```

But doesn't works

Comment: What the hell are you trying to do?

Comment: @EdHeal That's enough coffee for you.  :)

Comment: @EdHeal Initialize with NULL all values of callbacks in class A...

Comment: @DrewDormann - I do not drink coffee. I just do not understand the narrative of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for your definition is wrong.

Change

```
void (* )[6]() A::callbacks[6]
```

to

```
void (*A::callbacks[6])()
```

Comment: +1 for a `typedef`-less solution. Anno I had a hard time figuring out the syntax for this.

Comment: @H2CO3 **Years** of practice and I can *usually* do it from memory.  :)

Comment: @H2CO3 - I feel sorry for the person that will be maintaining this code

Comment: @EdHeal Me too, nevertheless this solution is my favorite :)

Comment: I want to avoid using typedef... =]

Comment: @H2CO3 - If that code landed on my desk it would go into the shredder but not his P45 (pink slip for the Americans I believe)

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void(*T)();
T A::callbacks[6] = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
```